# What is this plant with ivy-like leaves and pink flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

Can you help me identify this plant? Is it a vine?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does look similar to a geranium.

Answer (score 5):

This plant is a Pelargonium Peltatum / Ivy-Leaved Pelargonium. It's closely related to the zonal pelargoniums. (And hence often somewhat mixed up)

Typical characteristics are

- waxy, ivy-shaped leaves
- long distances between the leaf nodes and thus
- trailing or hanging growth, suitable for window boxes, hanging baskets or similar
- often, but not always with flower clusters that apperar more sparse or "thinner" then their p. zonatum relatives.

In Central Europe (where I live), Pelargoniums are "the" plant for window boxes etc., so I've seen my share of them. Especially the ivy-leaved P.s (simply called "Hängegeranie" / hanging pelargonium here) can look spectacular.

Comment: This answer is correct, point given - there's one on my balcony as I write, struggling to survive the winter, very common in Europe

Comment: I jest a bit - its in a sheltered corner, growing up a wall, out of the rain, and has been there 4 years, is currently 4 feet high. It's the wet cold that kills them, keep 'em dry and they survive up to 10 degrees of frost. It currently has eight flowers out!

Answer (score 1):

This plant has a common name of zonal geranium or [pelargonium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelargonium). They are native to South Africa but are more commonly seen as outdoor bedding plants where they are treated as annuals.

To positively identify this plant there should be hairs on the underside of the leaves and the flower should be similar to this:
[image: zonal geranium]
and the leaves should be similar to this
[image: pelargonium hortorum]

Comment: I don't see any points on the leaf margins of the plants you pictured, or any gloss. It doesn't look right.

Comment: Pelargoniums come in many varieties - sometimes with smooth, glossy, sometimes with fluffy leaves. OP's picture shows a variety that tends to have long stems between the laeves (often the smoother-leafed varieties), which are often left to hang/trail over balconies or from hanging pots. @kevinsky's pictures show a "upright" variety that doesn't need support.